# Angular For Each Loop Behaviour

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I have a JSON File which has details about some books:

JSON File (I've pasted it just to show the parameters):

```
{
    "books": [{
        "bookId":101,"bookTitle":"Angular JS","topic":"Angular JS",
        "author":"Green",
        "cost":375,
        "imgUrl":"images/AngularJS1.JPG",
        "issued":true
    }, {
        "bookId":102,
        "bookTitle":"Instant Angular JS Starter",
        "topic":"Angular JS",
        "author":"Dan Menard",
        "cost":150,
        "imgUrl":"images/AngularJS2.JPG",
        "issued":true
    }, {
        "bookId":103,
        "bookTitle":"Ng-Book:The Complete Book on Angular JS",
        "topic":"Angular JS",
        "author":"Ari Lerner",
        "cost":4657,
        "imgUrl":"images/AngularJS3.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":104,
        "bookTitle":"Developing BackbonJS Applications",
        "topic":"Backbone JS",
        "author":"Addy Osmani",
        "cost":650,
        "imgUrl":"images/BackboneJS1.JPG",
        "issued":true
    }, {
        "bookId":105,
        "bookTitle":"Backbone.js Patterns and Best Practices",
        "topic":"Backbone JS",
        "author":"Swarnendu De",
        "cost":390,
        "imgUrl":"images/BackboneJS2.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":106,
        "bookTitle":"Backbone.js Cookbook",
        "topic":"Backbone JS",
        "author":"Vadim Mirgorod",
        "cost":240,
        "imgUrl":"images/BackboneJS3.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":107,
        "bookTitle":"Ember.js in Action",
        "topic":"Ember JS",
        "author":"Joachim Haagen Skeie",
        "cost":2500,
        "imgUrl":"images/EmberJS1.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":108,
        "bookTitle":"Mastering Ember.js",
        "topic":"EmberJS",
        "author":"Mitchel Kelonye",
        "cost":3500,
        "imgUrl":"images/EmberJS2.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":109,
        "bookTitle":"Developing an Ember JS Edge",
        "topic":"EmberJS",
        "author":"Jamie White and Matthew Beale",
        "cost":2000,
        "imgUrl":"images/EmberJS3.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":110,
        "bookTitle":"Node.js in Action",
        "topic":"NodeJS",
        "author":"Mike Cantelon and Marc Harter",
        "cost":800,
        "imgUrl":"images/NodeJS1.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":111,
        "bookTitle":"Node.js the Right Way",
        "topic":"NodeJS",
        "author":"Jim R. Wilson",
        "cost":1200,
        "imgUrl":"images/NodeJS2.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }, {
        "bookId":112,
        "bookTitle":"Pro Node.js for Developers",
        "topic":"NodeJS",
        "author":"Colin Ihrig",
        "cost":2800,
        "imgUrl":"images/NodeJS3.JPG",
        "issued":false
    }]
}
```

I'm accessing this JSON file using $http service of Angular JS in a controller.

I finally display the details in an HTML, I want to add a currency symbol using my own custom filter, below is the code.

HTML Code:

```
<table>
<tr class="LoginFormDiv" ng-repeat="iterator in variable|orderBy:sort |filter:mySearch|addRupeeSymbol">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>
        <img src="{{iterator.imgUrl}}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Book Id:</td><td>{{iterator.bookId}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Book Title:</td><td>{{iterator.bookTitle}}</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Book Topic:</td><td>{{iterator.topic}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Book Author:</td><td>{{iterator.author}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Book Cost:</td><td>{{iterator.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Issued</td><td>{{iterator.issued}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button ng-disabled="iterator.issued == true" ng-click="issueBook(iterator.bookId)"> Issue </button>
                    <button ng-disabled="iterator.issued == false" ng-click="returnBook(iterator.bookId)"> Return </button>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The "addRupeeSymbol" is my custom filter.

Custom Filter:

```
var myFilter = angular.module('myFilter', []);

myFilter.filter('addRupeeSymbol', function() {
    return function(input) {        
        var costWithRupeeSymbol = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function(value, index) {
            value.cost = "Rs." + value.cost;
            costWithRupeeSymbol.push(value);
        });     

        return costWithRupeeSymbol;
    }
});
```

When the code is executed I get the output as RsRsRsRsRsRsRsRsRsRsRs375, why is this happening I'm unable to understand how this for loop is behaving here.
Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of filters: array filter and value filter. You use array filter when work with ng-repeat for example (ng-repeat="item in someArray | myFilter"). In this case myFilter get as parameter the whole array, and your myFilter function works as expected.

On the other hand value filter get as parameter only that value. So, you can change value (set format to it), but you don't have access to all array values.

The point is, you should create value filter for formatting:

```
var myFilter = angular.module('myFilter',[]);
myFilter.filter('addRupeeSymbol', function(){

return function(input) {    
    return 'Rs.' + input;
}
```

**UPD**

> What is reason that the loop is running more than 12 times?

Digest cycle run every time when some value has changed. You changed array in the filter procedure

```
value.cost = "Rs." + value.cost;
```

And it fires digest event. If you add line

```
console.log('filter run');
```

on top of the filter procedure, you'll see than this code runs 11 times before fails.

```
filter('addRupeeSymbol', function() {
    return function(input) {        

        console.log('filter run');

        var costWithRupeeSymbol = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function(value, index) {
            value.cost = "Rs." + value.cost;
            costWithRupeeSymbol.push(value);
        });     

        return costWithRupeeSymbol;
    }
})
```

And that is infinite loop. If you comment line where value.cost is changing, then message "filter run" occurred only 2 times (one for initialization and one for actual running)

```
filter('addRupeeSymbol', function() {
    return function(input) {        

        console.log('filter run');

        var costWithRupeeSymbol = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function(value, index) {
            // value.cost = "Rs." + value.cost;
            costWithRupeeSymbol.push(value);
        });     

        return costWithRupeeSymbol;
    }
})
```

I can't really think of a good example, you just have to make no changes to array in your filter. More on digest at [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Comment: I've tried the way you suggested, but I want to know why does the loop fails to edit the element of the array with only one Rs. Symbol, it adds 11 symbols to it why so? What is reason that the loop is running more than 12 times?

Comment: @user3077946 That's because you make changes to array angular.forEach(input, function(value, index) { value.cost = "Rs." + value.cost; costWithRupeeSymbol.push(value); }); You can't change value.cost at filter definition, cause if you do angular see that change and run digest cycle once again, then run your filter, make changes to value.cost see that change and run diges cycle again and again... In array filter you just can push already existed elements to result array (costWithRupeeSymbol) without changing them.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `input` length is 7. You shouldn't use angular foreach loop in the filter, unless you want to have Rs. before every character.
Here is an example:

```
var myFilter = angular.module('myFilter', []);
myFilter.filter('addRupeeSymbol', function () {
    return function (cost) {
        return 'Rs.'+cost;
    }
}
```